# Получение информации с js на pyscript

Tags: javascript, html, pyscript

```
var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("vaule1").value);
var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML);
var c = a + b;
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = c
alert("Dabloons successfully sent!")
pyscript.runtime.interpreter.runPython(`
        print(c)
`)
```

мне надо получить переменую C из js в pyscript как я могу это сделать (документацию читал там есть только с pyscript на js )

Comment: Если в косых кавычках - это строка, то можно точно так же как если бы просто вставляли значение в строку.

Comment: Что-то типа ```pyscript.runtime.interpreter.runPython(`python(${c})`)```, возможно еще нужно добавить кавычки, если там строка: ```pyscript.runtime.interpreter.runPython(`python("${c}")`)```

Comment: можете пожалуйста привести пример этого кода я не понимаю просто куда print деть

Comment: Вместо последних трех строк в вашем коде вставляете одну как я показал